# How to save the generated HTML from wysihtml5 or pass it to PHP page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I am using [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) to implement WYSIHTML Editor in my bootstrap site. But I dont get hoow can I pass the HTML content to a php page in order to save the content in database. Though I have used ID(content) for the textarea but the php page is not getting data. The URL by "Get" shows "?_wysihtml5_mode=1" at the end instead of something like "?content=..."

```
<form action="save.php" method="get">
   <textarea class="textarea" id="content" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form> 

<script>$('#content').wysihtml5(); </script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you post the HTML content to your PHP script?

Comment: I have just given the php page url in form->action. Does it require special code to pass HTML code.

Comment: Can you show you current html/js code to understand what you are doing? Because yes I'm pretty sure you have to retrieve the html content and post it explicitely to the PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: You need to add a name attribute to your textarea for it to be posted to your PHP. I completely forgot this. So forget every other modifications I did, just do this to your textarea in your original code :

```
<textarea class="textarea" id="content" name="content" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
```

You should also send the values through a POST request because sending the html in the URL arguments is not a good idea.

*Old Answer:*

You need to also post the html when submitting the form. There are multiple ways to do this but as an example you can add an hidden input field in which you will store the html before sending it to php.

First I changed a bit your html, the form is now sent through a POST request which is better than through the URL arguments if you want to send HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="save.php" method="POST">
   <textarea class="textarea" id="content" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
   <input type="hidden" id="html" />
</form>
```

Add the javascript event to change the hidden field value before submitting the value:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
   // Retrieve the HTML from the plugin
   var html = $('#content').val();
   // Put this in the hidden field
   $("#html").val(html);
});
```

Comment: still I am not getting it. I guess there is something with "?_wysihtml5_mode=1" this is the value being passed to php when I post it using get. May be some thing from WYSIHTML is making this happen.

Comment: @AlokKumar Do you retrieve the value with `$_POST['html']` in your php code? can you add `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: It says
array (size=1)
  '_wysihtml5_mode' => string '1' (length=1)

Also wamp shows error Notice: Undefined index: content in C:\wamp\www\desto\final\site\showProfile.php on line 3

cause 'content' is not being sent

Comment: @AlokKumar Does it say this for `$_GET` or `$_POST` ?

Comment: Googling it I found this. But I dont understand what does it mean to say
https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Neat-Extras

Comment: it says same thing for both get and post

Comment: @AlokKumar Check my edit!! I'm sorry I made you change all this for nothing, you're just missing the name attribute for the textarea

Comment: oh! thanks @koopajah I didnt know textarea won't work without name attribute. Now it works fine. Thanks again. A silly mistake has taken so much time. But I'm happy that I learnt a new lesson today regarding Textarea. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's not specific to textarea. You need the attribute "name" if you want an input to be sent through a submit in a POST or GET request. It is the same for your button : it does not have a name attribute so it is not sent!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('#content').wysihtml5();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn btn-primary').click(function() {
        var content = $('#content').html();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                content: content
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form>
   <textarea class="textarea" id="content" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

update.php

```
<?php
DATABASE_CONNECTION

$GET_THE_CONTENT_HERE = $_POST[content];

INSERT TO DATABASE
?>
```

Comment: still I am not getting it. I guess there is something with "?_wysihtml5_mode=1" this is the value being passed to php when I post it using get. May be some thing from WYSIHTML is making this happen.